# Amazon Cognito Identity error: "Unable to store key" Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to access Amazon S3 bucket using Amazon Cognito Identity credentials in Xamarin iOS. I have assinged "s3FullAccess" policy to both roles associated with the identity pool.

Code:

```c#
CognitoAWSCredentials credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials("us-west-2:*******-...", RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

IAmazonS3 s3Client; = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest()
{
   BucketName = Constants.AwsS3Bucket,
   InputStream = dataStream,
   ContentType = contentType,
   Key = "fileKey"
};

await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(putObjectRequest).ContinueWith((Task task) => {
  if (task.Exception != null) throw (task.Exception);
});
```

This gives me following exception:

`Application Settings exception, Unable to store key CognitoIdentity:IdentityId:us-west-2:*******-..., got error: Param`

Comment: Try to Enable Keychain Access Groups.

Comment: Already done it, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error throws when Cognito SDK tries to access the keychain. I managed to fix this error on the simulator by adding a provisioning profile.